# Migrating the items of a SharePoint 2013 to a SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2013, 2016, content-migration, excel-import

I am willing to migrate documents and functionalities of a SharePoint site from a 2013 version to a 2016 version with site’s peculiarities, steps, and first unsuccessful attempts detailed below. Would you know how to do it?

Peculiarities :

The main document is a data list (see below), that people of level A fill with a form. The data is then validated by people of level B for people of level C (me) to use the data.

[image: screenshot1]

Steps :

Any help on the steps below would be helpful :

1. above all, importing an Excel tab to the new SharePoint 2016 site
2. if possible, importing the form used to fill the data (see below)
3. if possible, importing other characteristics such as the data validation workflow

[image: screenshot2]

First attempt :

1. The export from excel to a SharePoint as detailed in the Microsoft help (https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/exporter-un-tableau-excel-vers-sharepoint-974544f9-94bc-4aa8-9159-97282d256dab?ui=fr-fr&rs=fr-fr&ad=fr&fromar=1) is unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the 2013 Content DB to new farm and upgrade, if facing issues you can run the site in compatibility mode. The workflow you have seems to be custom one so it might need to be rebuild for the SP2016 farm.
Here you have reference that should put you on the right track:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/copy-databases-to-the-new-farm-for-upgrade-to-sharepoint-server-2016

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer and the confirmation that I needed to recreate the workflow.

I finally succeeded to import the Excel tab by:

1. Exporting the excel file from the 2013 version, which also created a .iqy file
2. In the 2016 version : parameters --> site's content --> add an application --> import a spreadsheet --> import the .iqy file (several steps)